# Liquibase generate diff with Springboot 3

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, jakarta-migration

I'm trying to generate liquibase-scripts with liquibase 4.18.0 and Spring Boot 3.0.1.

And i'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.18.0:diff (default-cli) on project ims-backend: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.18.0:diff failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.18.0:diff: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo()'
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.18.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin/4.18.0/liquibase-maven-plugin-4.18.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/4.18.0/liquibase-core-4.18.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/opencsv/opencsv/5.7.1/opencsv-5.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-text/1.10.0/commons-text-1.10.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.4/commons-collections4-4.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-commercial/4.18.0/liquibase-commercial-4.18.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
```

It seems that

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo()
```

returns now

```
jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo
```

instead of

```
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo
```

Is there anyting i can do about it, or is the only option to wait for a new liquibase version?

Comment: You have to wait for a liquibase version that supports JakartaEE.

Answer (score 5):

Ok i could fix the problem when using liquibase-hibernate6 instead of liquibase-hibernate5

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But i had to override liquibase.version to 4.18.0 in my project, because it is only available for 4.18 and spring boot currently uses 4.17

```
<liquibase.version>4.18.0</liquibase.version>
```

Furthermore i had to change

```
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

into

```
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
```

Comment: i am getting this error 

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
 a